# Rails: Marking content as complete for individual users, when content is common across them

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm relatively new to Rails, so apologies in advance if this is an obvious question. I could not find an answer through searching.

I'm building a basic application which acts as an educational course - users can view lessons, take in the content, and mark lessons as 'complete' accordingly.

I would like users to be able to see which lessons are complete, by marking them as such in the course overview.

I have a Users model and a Lessons model, and the lessons are identical per user at present. If lessons were unique per user, this would presumably be solvable with a boolean 'complete' column for each lesson. This is not the case in this application, however - some users will have completed a lesson; others will not have.

How would I best go about a solution to this? All suggestions and ideas welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use many-many association and establish relationship among the 3 models.

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :progresses
   has_many :subjects, through: :progresses
end

class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :progresses
  has_many :students, through: :progresses
end

class Progress < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :student 
  belongs_to :subject
end
```

To be precise use [this](http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/ar-many_to_many.html) link to get good understanding on many-many association :)

Answer (score 0):

Third model, say `Progress` or `Completion` or `Grades` or `UserLessons`... that will belong to user and lesson, and have a field called `complete` or `score` or `grade`....

Answer (score 0):

It's a classic case of many-to-many relation.

```
User can read multiple lessons
Lessons could be read/complete by multiple users
```

So to do this is to create another model with   column `user_id` `lesson_id` as a foreign key for user and lesson and create an additional column `completed` boolean